# Pytesser inaccurate

Tags: python, ocr

Simple question. When I run [this](http://www.theadamgaskins.com/upload/326_fail.jpg) image through pytesser, i get `$+s`. How can I fix that?

**EDIT**

So... my code generates images similar to the image linked above, just with different numbers, and is supposed to solve the simple math problem, which is obviously impossible if all I can get out of the picture is `$+s`

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
from pytesser import *

time.sleep(2)
i = 0
operator = "+"
while i < 100:
    time.sleep(.1);
    img = ImageGrab.grab((349, 197, 349 + 452, 197 + 180))
    equation = image_to_string(img)
```

Then I'm going to go on to parse `equation`... as soon as I get pytesser working.

Comment: Care to explain why this was voted down?

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: Yes I can, this question needs a lot more information, for example what is your relevant code, also it would be good if you could post what have you tried to do so far to fix it, so the people are not "doning

Comment: Sorry can't edit the previous one for some reason, I was saying, so that the ones that are answering your question don't have to do all the heavy lifting and all the work to you, this is supposed to be collaboration, if you add more information and make this a complete question, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: Is really hard to answer this question accurately without some more context, like the exact code you're using to run the image through pytesser, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my little function. I'm running `tesseract` from the `svn` repo, so my results might be more accurate.

I'm on Linux, so on Windows, I'd imagine that you'll have to replace `tesseract` with `tesseract.exe` to make it work.

```
import tempfile, subprocess

def ocr(image):
  tempFile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False)

  process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', image, tempFile.name], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
  process.communicate()

  handle = open(tempFile.name + '.txt', 'r').read()

  return handle
```

And a sample Python session:

```
>>> import tempfile, subprocess
>>> def ocr(image):
...   tempFile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete = False)
...   process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', image, tempFile.name], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
...   process.communicate()
...   handle = open(tempFile.name + '.txt', 'r').read()
...   return handle
... 
>>> print ocr('326_fail.jpg')
0+1
```

Comment: You're using a really old version of Python. I do this on 2.7 and 3.0!

Answer (score 1):

if you're in linux, use **gocr** is more accurate. you can use it through

```
os.system("/usr/bin/gocr %s") % (sample_image)
```

and use readlines from stdout for manipulating output result to everything what you want (i.e creating output from gocr for specific variable).